# Indexing string for insertion into char[][][] array

Tags: java, arrays, string, charat

I'm a little stuck on the arithmetic for this program. I have a string `theString` that has a length of `x*y*z`. `x`, `y`, and `z` are the dimensions of a char[][][] array (lets call it `cArr`).

I want to insert the characters of `theString` into `cArr` based on a specific index. Here's an example of a 5x4x3 array.

```
String theString = someMethod(); //returns a string of length 60
char[][][] cArr = new char[5][4][3];
for (int z = 0; z < 3; z++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
            cArr[x][y][z] = theString.charAt(/*~~~*/);
        }
    }
}
```

I can figure out the arithmetic to insert characters into a char[5][4] array from a string of length 20:

```
for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
        cArr[x][y] = theString.charAt((5*y)+x);
    }
}
```

What arithmetic should I be using in the `charAt()` method for a 3-dimensional char array?

My best attempt has been:

```
char[][][] cArr = new char[5][4][3];
for (int z = 0; z < 3; z++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
            cArr[x][y][z] = theString.charAt(((3^2)*z)+(4*y)+x);
        }
    }
}
```

But this makes all z-index layers of `cArr` the same.

Comment: Using [this terminology](http://i.ytimg.com/vi/mIJXeNWIE1E/hqdefault.jpg): number of full panes times cubes in a pane + number of full columns (in a partial pane) times cubes in a column + number of cubes in a partial column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rule is simple for problems like this. You start from the innermost loop and proceed up with `x + y*(length of x) + z*(length of y)*(length of x)`.

In this example, it would be,

```
cArr[x][y][z] = theString.charAt(x + y*5 + z*4*5);
```